# How to enable a plugin from a link in an admin notification in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I added a notification (using `admin_notices` hook) in my theme code to show a banner talking about a partner plugin. In that banner I need to add a link that activates the plugin for me. Is that possible?

I've tried using `get_admin_url` with no luck (got redirected to an "are you sure?" page that did nothing).

Comment: Here's the documentation for the activate_plugin function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/activate_plugin

Perhaps there is some clever way to trigger this when the user clicks a link in that admin notice...

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently activate a plugin with the activate_plugin function, documented here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/activate_plugin

That requires PHP to run, which you cannot trigger by clicking a link in JavaScript. What you could do is create some hidden admin page (https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-wordpress-admin-pages/), which contains your activate_plugin code. When the user clicks the link in your admin notice, you just link them to this page, which runs the activate code. You should consider checking to see if the plugin is actually present in the plugins directory and that it is not already activated.

Then maybe redirects the user somewhere else so they get a decent experience.

Comment: Hey Jason, I fixed the "are you sure?" problem by generating a nonce code and adding it to the generated url. Which called the default activate plugin action in wordpress admin.
Your idea would be good to be able to do anything with custom admin pages and easter eggs and what not to the user. +1